# Django signal to follow/unfollow

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have a signal that looks like this:

```
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Following)
def increment_follow_count(instance, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.follower.following_count += 1
        instance.target.follower_count += 1
    else:
        instance.follower.following_count -= 1
        instance.target.follower_count -= 1
```

When a user follows another user, it works correctly. However, when that same user unfollows that user, only the person that the user followed (target) has their follower count decremented, but the user's following count is not decremented. Why is this behavior happening and how can I fix it?

**Model:**

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is followed by {}'.format(self.target, self.follower)
```

**Code to follow/unfollow user**

```
def follow_unfollow(follower, target):
    # Query to see if the following exists or not
    following = target.followers.filter(follower=follower)

    if following.exists():
        following.delete()
    else:
        target.followers.create(follower=follower)

    target.save()
    follower.save()
```

Comment: Please share the model definitions, I suspect that, the receiver is listening wrong object change and does not track related model update properly

Comment: @GiorgiJambazishvili Hi, I just updated the question with the model

Comment: are you deleting the object when the user unfollow other user? if yes then you need to use post_delete signal. Can you add some more code to show the flow of unfollowing users?

Comment: @NalinDobhal Also, I am using post_delete take a look at the signal

Comment: may be you have to just add one method into you model change count where you can catch each change, and then just call it when you make post save

Answer (score 0):

`increment_follow_count` signal contains increment logic but no save logic and saving is done is another `follow_unfollow` method?

---

First, **increment** is better to **be atomic**, to make sure no changes are lost.

Atomic increment can be achieved using [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

```
from django.db.models import F

@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Following)
def increment_follow_count(instance, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        User.objects.filter(
            pk=instance.follower_id
        ).update(
            following_count=F('following_count') + 1
        )
        User.objects.filter(
            pk=instance.target_id
        ).update(
            following_count=F('following_count') + 1
        )
    else:
        User.objects.filter(
            pk=instance.follower_id
        ).update(
            following_count=F('following_count') - 1
        )
        User.objects.filter(
            pk=instance.target_id
        ).update(
            following_count=F('following_count') - 1
        )
```

Here increment is not only atomic, but changes are immediately saved 
in the database in the same method.

Also, I would suggest to **remove `target.save()` and `follower.save()` in `follow_unfollow`** - as it *overwrites* instance in database with the values in memory, and this *should not be the case*, at least for `following_count` as its increment logic is in signal. If in `follow_unfollow` method some changes to fields, other than `followng_count` are done - then `save()` should be called with [`update_fields` list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) to update only changed fields.

---

Regular `+= 1` takes current in-memory instance field value, i.e. `count=5`, increment (`count=6`), and *later*, when save is called, it is being saved as update `count=6`. And during this time value might have already changed in database many times (and update will set it to 6 regardless), especially under load / simultaneous actions.

With atomic increment logic is moved from python to database - and will increment actual value at the time transaction is made.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `in increment_follow_count
    following_count=F('following_count') - 1
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: In a queryset (User.objects.filter().update(f_c=F('f_c')-1))? Seems like field is called / modified directly on instance, not in queryset.

Comment: Ah it was an import issue, no errors no but this doesn't seem to update the following_count for some reason

Comment: Is `target.save(); follower.save()` removed from `follow_unfollow`?

Comment: Is `target.save()` / `follower.save()` in other places while follow / unfollow action? Log of database SQL queries when user clicks follow / unfollow button would be helpful.